# compare single column of two files

Tags: bash, grep

I have two files, each with two columns separated by a space.

I'd like to find the lines in which column 2 is not the same in both files and output them to a third file.

file A:

```
1 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
3 CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
4 DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
5 EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
6 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
7 GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
8 HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

file B:

```
1 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
3 CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
4 DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
5 WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
6 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
7 YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
8 ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
9 EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
10 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
11 GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
12 HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

desired output:

```
5 WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
6 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
7 YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
8 ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

I assumed the easiest way to do this was `grep` each line from file A in file B, but I'm new to bash and can't figure out the next step. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a && a[$1] != $2' fileA fileB
5 WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
6 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
7 YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
8 ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

It loops through the first file storing the values in an array `a[1st col] = 2nd col`. Then, it loops through the second file and prints those lines matching these conditions:

- The first column is present in the first file.
- The second column value is different from the one in the first file.

To store it into a new file, just redirect the command to a file:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a && a[$1] != $2' fileA fileB > fileC
                                                                  ^^^^^^^
```