# compare single column of two files line by line

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I've asked a similar question to this before but didn't find the exact answer I was looking for, I apologize for redundancy. I decided to repost the question phrased differently. I have two lengthy files, each with two columns separated by a space.

I'd like to eliminate all lines that have a matching column 2 in fileA and fileB (regardless of line number/column 1), and output the entire mismatching-line to a separate file.

File A:

```
1 AA
2 BB
3 CC
4 DD
5 EE
6 FF
7 GG
8 HH
```

File B:

```
1 AA
2 BB
3 XX
4 XX
5 CC
6 DD
7 XX
8 FF
9 GG
10 XX
11 XX
12 HH
```

Desired output:

```
3 XX
4 XX
7 XX
5 EE
10 XX
11 XX
```

[fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29372829) suggested I use awk to store the second column of fileA in an array, then loop through fileB to output lines with the following criteria:

1. column 1 is present in fileA
2. but column 2 in fileB is different

   ```
   awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a && a[$1] != $2' fileA fileB
   ```

This is helpful until my code encounters the first discrepancy in column 2 between fileA and fileB, then the code outputs all following lines.

Instead of this, I would like to compare the array from column 2 of fileA line-by-line to column 2 of fileB. Once the code encounters a discrepancy, it outputs the entire mismatched line from fileB, then compares the same line of the array to the next line of fileB. It continues comparing the same line of the array, outputing discrepant lines of fileB until a match is found. If the code reaches the end of fileB and no match is found, then output the line from fileA, move to the next line of the array and continue comparing to each line of fileB. Is this possible, or any easier way to do this than creating an array with awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$0;next} $2 in a{del[$2];next} 1;
     END{for (i in a) if (!(i in del)) print a[i]}' fileA fileB
3 XX
4 XX
7 XX
10 XX
11 XX
5 EE
```

Note order is not as shown in question because `(fileA - fileB)` is printed in the end while `(fileB - fileA)` is computed while traversing `fileB`.

Comment: This has gotten me closer, thank you. However, when I run this on my true fileA and fileB, I notice there are many lines that are not discrepant between fileA and fileB which appear in the output. Many of these lines are repeats of the same letter (for example, CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC and ####################################). Do you know why this might occur?

Comment: If you provide new sample data from both files in question then I can certainly look into that and suggest a fix.

Comment: thanks anubhava. Here is a link to a github that contains the script I ran (awk_diff.sh). It also contains the first 20 lines of output (head20_output.fastq) and lines 6130-6400 of fileA and fileB. Notice that lines 6144, 6268 and 6380 are in the both fileA and fileB column 2 on the same line, but appear in the output.  https://github.com/agrobins/awk_diff/