# Comparing column of two files

Tags: awk

I want to compare the first column of two csv files. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372798/compare-single-column-of-two-files) answer and tried to adapt it minimally (I want the first column, not the second and I want a print out on any mismatch, regardless of whether the value was present in a control column).

I thought this would be the way to go:

```
BEGIN { FS = "," } 
{
if(FNR==NR) {a[$1]=$1} 
else {if (a[$1] != $1) {print}}
}
```

[Here I have already removed one Syntax Error thanks to comment by RavinderSingh13]

The first line was supposed to set the separator to comma.
The second line was supposed to fill the array exactly for as long as I am still reading the first file.
The third line was to compare the elements of the first column of the second file elementwise to said array. Then print the entire line with a mismatch.

However, if I apply this to the following tiny files, which differ in the first non-header entry:
output2.csv:

```
#ID,COU,YEA,VOT# 
4238,"CHN",2000,1
4239,"CHN",2000,1
4239,"CHN",2000,1
4240,"CHN",2000,1
```

and output.csv:

```
#ID,COU,YEA,VOT# 
4237,"CHN",2000,1
4238,"CHN",2000,1
4239,"CHN",2000,1
4240,"CHN",2000,1
```

I dont get any print out. I call it like this:

> ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Jason$ gawk -f compare_col_print_diff.awk output.csv output2.csv
> ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Jason$

Comment: You need to place `{` before `if` and add one closing `}` at last then it should be fine. We need to call if conditions inside `{...}` only.

Comment: Yes, this removes the syntax error, but it doesnt work as intended! But thank you vewry much!

Comment: Without seeing your samples its not possible to help on Logic part honestly, please do add samples and let us know then for better understanding of your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 of course! I will add a malfunctioning example in a minute! Thank you very much!

Comment: If you change the order of the inputfiles (`gawk -f compare_col_print_diff.awk output2.csv output.csv`) you will see `4237` in the output. Or, in more words, All numbers in output2 do exist in output, but not all numbers in output do exist in output2.

Comment: @Luuk aha! This is very instructive!

Comment: No, because i did not define the sample files , but more seriously the solution you are using is, reading all values from the first file ('output.csv'), and then comparing each line to the second file('output2.csv). All numbers in output2.csv do exist in output.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for line by line comparison, it's easier to match the records first

```
$ paste -d, file1 file2 | awk -F, '$1!=(f=$(NF/2+1)){print NR":",$1, f}'
```

will print values for which the first fields don't agree.

With your input files, this will give

```
2: 4238 4237
3: 4239 4238
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment by Luuk made me realise a huge fundamental error in my original script, which I think should be recorded. The instruction

```
a[$1]=$1
```

Does not produce an array entry per line, but an array entry per distinct  ID. Hence, such array is no basis for general strict comparison of the files. To remedy this, I wrote the following, which works on the example, but may still contain traps, as I am still learning:

```
BEGIN { FS = "," } 
{
if(FNR==NR) {a[NR]=$1} 
else {if (a[FNR] != $1) {print FNR, $0}}
}
```

Producing:

```
$ gawk -f compare_col_print_diff.awk output.csv output2.csv
2 4238,"CHN",2000,1
3 4239,"CHN",2000,1
```